# Is there an [embed] alternative for Flash only (not flex)?

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, flash-cs5

Ok we all know that you can embed assets with Flex using the [embed] code.

But is there anyway to achieve something similar to this when working with only Flash?

For example:
I need to create a class (that contains certain assets) that needs to be used in the Flash IDE, but I don't want to have to drop all the assets into the library for every Flash file that happens to use the class.

Comment: Are you looking for this? http://www.adobe.com/devnet/flash/articles/embed_metadata.html

Comment: AsTheWormTurns seriously that is fantastic - change your comment to an answer and I will accept it

Comment: I did it, even if this kind of answer is not generally tolerated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you looking for this? http://adobe.com/devnet/flash/articles/embed_metadata.html

Comment: I don't see why it wouldn't be tolerated. Cheers once again, very helpful!

Comment: @Chris: as far as I know, they prefer more argumentative replies.  :-)

Answer (score 1):

Hope this will helpful for you.

http://www.adobe.com/devnet/flex/articles/actionscript_blitting.html
http://blog.nightspade.com/2010/02/01/embedding-asset-at-compile-time-in-pure-as3-project/
http://www.bit-101.com/blog/?p=853